# How to handle if wrong item specified in Material Autocomplete

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm using [material autocomplete](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview) in my Angular app. But the trouble I'm facing is I have no idea how to handle if someone specified or entered an item which is not in the list. If someone selected an element from the list, I am handling it and based on the key I'm populating the page using data binding.

Here is my code

**HTML**

```
  <form class = "tp-form">
    <mat-form-field class = "tp-full-width">
       <input type = "text" 
          placeholder = "Project Code" 
          aria-label = "PCODE" 
          matInput 
          [formControl] = "myPcodes" 
          [matAutocomplete] = "auto">
          <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="onPcodeChange($event)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
              {{option}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
 </form>
```

**TS**

```
  onPcodeChange(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent) {
    let pCode: string = event.option.value;
    //let pName:string = this.projects.find(x=>x.projectCode=pCode).projectName;
    //alert(pName);
    this.myProject = this.projects.find(x => x.projectCode = pCode);

   }
```

So what I'm trying to achieve is, if the user types a wrong item, it must clear the myProject object, so ofcourse my form get cleared since its data bound with that object

Comment: Check the return value from `find` method. If it is null leave `myProject` unchanged?

Comment: Sorry.. that will not fire since user manually type in the value rather than selecting from autocomplete list. It will fire only when the user select the value from the list

Comment: Try using (change) on your <input>, that should fire, if the user manually enters something -> then you can clear it

Comment: @AliNasserzadeh I tried (change) in that input. But that doest worked since if we type 12 the auto complete willl show the list with 12, and if we select 12345, even then the change event has just 12 in textbox. it doesnt show 12345

Comment: you need to use both the change event of the input and the onPcodeChange that you have in place

Comment: It seems you need a dropdown with a filter feature rather than autocomplete.

Comment: @AliNasserzadeh That was I was able to achieve it.. But though about a more pro way

Comment: @Eldar No, its autocomplete, but filtered (based on each of the character the user types in)